# Android Studio Debugging External Fingerprint Application

Tags: android, debugging, adb, fingerprint, digital-persona-sdk

I am writing an *Android* application using *U.are.U 4500* fingerprint reader, so, my question is: how can I debug such an application?

I have device USB port busy (fingerprint is connected to), is there another way to debug without unplugging the fingerprint reader?

Note: device is not rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADB supports TCP/IP ...therefore one can use the debug bridge via WiFi.

there are many [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=adb%20wifi) answering it.